# How to filter output lines from bash command based on directorys

Tags: linux, awk, filter, grep

I have a file called sftp_output with the output of command from a sftp connection that list the content of some folders and look like this:

```
sftp> ls -l dir1/
-rw-------   1 200      100          1352 Jul 01 14:20 file1
-rw-------   1 200      100          1352 Jul 10 14:20 file2
sftp> ls -l dir2/
-rw-------   1 200      100          1352 Jul 01 14:20 file1
-rw-------   1 200      100          1352 Jul 10 14:20 file2
sftp> bye
```

What I need to do is filter all the files from dir1 to a single file called `"dir1_contents"` and files from dir2 to a file called `"dir2_contents"`
. What is the best approach to do something like that?

The expected result needs to be something like this.

File: dir1_contents

```
file1
file2
```

What I need to do is filter all the files from dir1 to a single file called `"dir1_contents"` and files from dir2 to a file called `"dir2_contents"`
. What is the best approach to do something like that?

I tried doing something like this

```bash
cat sftp_output | grep -v 'sftp' | awk '{print $9}'| sed '/^$/d'
```

Comment: The **best approach** you requested is to start over to come up with some other input format since what you are trying to parse is obviously the output of `ls` and you shouldn't try to parse that, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This single `awk` can handle this:

```bash
awk 'match($0,/ls +[^\/]+/) { # match a line that has ls command
   s=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)# get the matched substring into var s
   sub(/^ls +/, "", s)        # remove ls and 1+ spaces from s
   close(fn)                  # close file handle, if open
   fn = s "_contents"         # populate variable fn 
   next                       # move to next line
}
fn {                          # if fn is not empty
   print > fn                 # redirect current line to file `fn`
}' sftp_output
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=""
while read -r line; do
  if [ "${line#sftp> ls -l }" != "${line}" ]; then
    dir="${line#sftp> ls -l }"
    dir="${dir%/}"
  elif [ "${dir}" != "" ]; then
    echo "${line}" >> "${dir}_contents"
  fi
done < sftp_output
```

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: If performance is a concern, interpreted languages are not the solution. But the OP didn’t specify a performance requirement.

Comment: Awk scripts for text processing are often faster than complied C programs due to the awk code being highly optimized for text processing tasks while manually written C code usually isn't, e.g. see the timing at https://brenocon.com/blog/2009/09/dont-mawk-awk-the-fastest-and-most-elegant-big-data-munging-language/. But in any case, since there's no benefits to writing a shell loop while it will be orders of magnitude slower than an awk script and harder to write correctly , there's just no reason to write one.

Comment: There's more negatives to a shell loop to consider than just performance in the accepted answer in that question I referenced by the way.

Comment: Re: “…there’s just no reason to write one.”. I have to disagree. I can think of plenty of reasons. I agree that it is a sub-optimal solution. I agree that there are many reasons why one should consider other solutions. But that does not mean that there is “no reason” to use this one.

Comment: I'm honestly curious and completely open to persuasion - what would be a reason to write a shell loop for this?

Comment: Firstly, just a word of caution; "I can't think of a reason" != "There is no reason". Here is a reason from my own experience: "It is the only scripting language that is familiar to everyone on my development team." And another: "My professor specified the language." And another: "For consistency, because the rest of the system is written in bash.". I'm aware that these are situational reasons and perhaps you were thinking of only of technical reasons, but that illustrates the point in my first sentence.